# How to count the occurrences in multiple column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, multiple-columns

I have the following table in SQL

```
TV_Show | genre_1 | genre_2 |
  a     | action  | sci-fi  |
  b     | sci-fi  | comedy  |
  c     | comedy  | romance |
  d     | action  | sci-fi  |
  .     |    .    |    .    |
  .     |    .    |    .    |
  .     |    .    |    .    |
```

I want to run a query which will count the number of times each of the different, unique genres come up in the entire table. I want the following result. The order of this output doesn't matter:

```
action    2
sci-fi    3
comedy    2
romance   1
  .       .
  .       .
  .       .
```

What should the SQL Query be?

**Edit**
I have already tried running the following, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT genre1 OR genre2, COUNT(*) FROM tv_show GROUP BY genre1 OR genre2
```

**Edit 2**

This example is a simplification of what my actual SQL table is. My actual table has other columns with different data. But I only have two `genre` columns which I want to do the query on.

Comment: @Viki888, check my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select genre, count(*)
from ((select genre_1 as genre from tv_show) union all
      (select genre_2 as genre from tv_show)
     ) g
group by genre;
```

With a simple modification, you can add counts for each column:

```
select genre, count(*), sum(first), sum(second)
from ((select genre_1 as genre, 1 as first, 0 as second from tv_show) union all
      (select genre_2 as genre, 0, 1 from tv_show)
     ) g
group by genre;
```

Comment: Hi, I am new to SQL so please could you explain what the 't' and 'g' are?

Comment: @TrackFry . . . `g` is a table alias, which is required for derived tables in the `from` clause.

Comment: I'm sorry, what would my table alias be in this case? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: g names the preceding `from (...)`. SQL requires you to provide a (temporary, new) name there

Comment: @GordonLinoff what is the `genre` that you have written here? Is that the name of the table? Same for `tv_show`, is this referring to the name of my table?

Comment: @Caleth I'm sorry, I don't understand.Could you please give an example?

Comment: The things you are asking about are names that are introduced in the query, used in the query, and cease to exist after the query. tv_show is the exception, being your table

Comment: There isn't really an example beyond "If you tried @GordonLinoff's query without the g there, it would not be a valid query" and "The g can be replaced with any sequence of letters and numbers apart from existing names"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` expression along with `SUM()` function; `group by` the `genere` column like

```
sum(case when genre_1 = 'action' then 1 else 0 end) as Action,
sum(case when genre_1 = 'sci-fi' then 1 else 0 end) as Sci-Fi,
sum(case when genre_1 = 'comedy' then 1 else 0 end) as Comedy,
sum(case when genre_1 = 'romance' then 1 else 0 end) as Romance
```

Comment: Would I have to do this query for each genre one-by-one? Also, is it possible for you to show me the output?

Comment: @TrackFry, if you want to count per genere type then yes you will have to. Output would same as what you have posted in your question.

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't work. The example that I gave is a simplification of my table. In my actual table, I have more columns with other data. But I only have two `genre` columns. What would I need to change for it too work?